# how to modify configure or configure.ac script to look for a binary only in specified location

Tags: makefile, lex, autotools, configure

I am cross compiling `flex` for ARM, for which I have configured as below:

> ./configure CC=/opt/gcc-4.8.5-glibc-2.21-p1-2.6.35.9/arm-brcm-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-brcm-linux-gnueabi-gcc  --host=armeb-none-linux-gnueabi LD=/opt/gcc-4.8.5-glibc-2.21-p1-2.6.35.9/arm-brcm-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-brcm-linux-gnueabi-ld --prefix=/home/ravi/out/usr/

I have added a non default path with `CC` and a `--prefix` option in the `configure` script, but `configure` checks for an existing `flex` binary in the default `/usr/local/bin` location, as shown by this excerpt from `config.log`:

> ```
>  configure:14320: checking for flex
>  configure:14336: found /usr/bin/flex
>  configure:14347: result: flex
> ```

How can I modify the search path to include only the directory `/home/ravi/out/usr/bin`?  what needs to be modified in `configure.ac`?

Comment: Why is it a problem that the `configure` script finds `/usr/bin/flex`?  I'm not sure why it wants to use `flex` to build `flex`, but if it indeed does, then it surely wants a version that runs on the build system.

Comment: In any case, the `--prefix` is about where things will be installed by `make install`.  It has nothing to do with where `configure` or the compiler looks for needed tools or libraries.

Comment: Additionally, it's odd that you're specifying a C compiler and linker that do not match the `--host` descriptor you have also provided.  Get the `--host` option right, corresponding to an installed cross-compiler toolchain, and then you should not need to specify any of the individual tools explicitly.